# UBUNTU 12.04LTS and virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, virtualbox

When I used win xp as virtual machine under 10.04lts, it worked fine. we shared printers attached for win machines with different ip address. no issue. stable and reliable.

on upgrading the server to 12.04LTS, the USB port sharing has not been effective. The printer works sometime. Not reliable at all. I have registered vbox as advised on their website. have installed latest extension packs. but no go.

running 64bit kernel 3.5.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In a host terminal run this:

> **sudo usermod -aG vboxusers -yourusername-**

If this not work you have to:

**Uninstall Virtualbox-4.2**

**Re install**

**Re install extension pack**

USB should work. (worked for me)

Comment: did addition of user to group. tested - did not work. removed vbox and then re-installed via apt command. installed vbox 4.1.12 installed extension pack for same. did not work.